# Copy the first column of a .csv file into a new file

Tags: python

I know this is a very easy task, but i am acting pretty dumb right now and dont get it solved. I need to copy the first column of a .csv file including header into a newly created file. My code:

```
station = 'SD_01'
import csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(str( station ) + "_ED.csv", delimiter =';')
```

```
list1 = []
matrix1 = df[df.columns[0]].as_matrix()
list1 = matrix1.tolist()
```

```
with open('{0}_RRS.csv'.format(station),"r+") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(map(lambda x: [x], list1))
```

As result, my file has an empty line between the values, has no header (i could continue without the header, though) and something at the bottom which a can not identify.

```
>350
>
>351
>
>352
>
>...
>
>949
>
>950
>
>Ž‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ ¡¢
```

Just a short impression of the 1200+ lines

1. I am pretty sure that this is a very clunky way to do this; easyier ways are always welcome.
2. How do i get rid of all the empty lines and this crazy stuff in the end?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a column from a dataframe, it's returned as type Series - and the Series has a [built in to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_csv.html) method you can use. So you don't need to do any matrix casting or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('name.csv',delimiter=';')
first_column = df[[df.columns[0]]
first_column.to_csv('new_file.csv')
```